# Can access phpmyadmin but can't login (not found)

Tags: linux, phpmyadmin

This is my phpmyadmin virtual host :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName pma.myserver.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/phpmyadmin

    <Directory "/var/www/phpmyadmin">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

/var/www/phpmyadmin is a symlink pointing on /usr/share/phpmyadmin.

I can access my phpmyadmin login page on pma.myserver.com, but when i try to login in, the url on my url bar is http://pma.myserver.com/index.php and i am getting a 404 error page with :

The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.

Any idea of my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Verify that your directory/file permissions and ownership are appropriate for your Apache deployment. Also, if your system uses SELinux you may want to disable it at least temporarily for troubleshooting:

```
# setenforce 0
```

Be sure the symlink is setup correctly, as well.

Comment: That includes verifying SELinux is disabled? Also, what about if you remove SymLinksifOwnerMatch from the mixture? Anything in a .htaccess file for /usr/share/phpmyadmin that could be screwing things up?

Comment: I removed SymLinksifOwnerMatch and can not access pma.myserver.com anymore. By addind this option again, i can neither access my pma (i restared apache).

Comment: I don't know what is SELinux, and i never modified pma htaccess.

Comment: Well, just try running setenforce 0 ; if it fixes your problem it's related to a Linux hardening system on your machine. You can re-enable at anytime running setenforce 1 to revert to running (if it's enabled at all). This is likely if you are on Red Hat or CentOS.

Comment: since i removed SymLinksifOwnerMatch, i cannot access my pma anymore, however, i put it again and restart apache, but i still can't access... any idea ?

Comment: where should i put setenforce 0 ?

Comment: On the command line as root or using sudo. So you should be SSH'ed in.

Comment: Since i removed and re-put removed SymLinksifOwnerMatch option, i cannot access pma.myserver.com anymore, any idea ? Apache restarted...

Comment: You're going to have to provide logs for apache to help out at this point. check in /var/log/apache2 and /var/log/httpd they are likely the end-point for log files.

Comment: Well, you're going to need to address why that is first. Without any error output, we're just going to keep making poorly informed guesses as to what is happening.

Comment: the only thing i did was removing SymLinksifOwnerMatch as you asked me, then restarting apache, noting that pma.myserver.com was not accessible anymore, re-puting SymLinksifOwnerMatch, restarting apache, and noting that didn't make pma.myserver.com rework. i'd like make my pma.myserver.com act like when i write my first post...

Comment: I can't be held liable for what you edit or don't edit. This is StackOverflow, no one is here being paid to try and help you. If you can't provide log files, I don't know how you expect anyone to guess at what you've done or not done to fix this issue. Further, if you edited your configuration file but didn't make a backup copy first, I don't know how that's at all my responsibility. Don't ask for help and then place blame on people trying to give it to you. Hire someone if you want that sort of accountability.

Comment: i'm sorry if you didn't understand me, i didn't blame you at all, i just tried to explain (in english, which is not my language) how i get this problem. Now, i didn't need backup because i just removed temporarly this option, and nothing in my log file is about pma.myserver.com.

Comment: Thank you for everything, i wil try something diffent.